# get event logs and debug trace from eth_call

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, evm, ethereumjs, ethereumj

I am looking for a way to execute a transaction locally (using local geth/parity node) for simulation only, before actually submitting it to blockchain.

I know that I can use 'eth_call' RPC call and It will return the function's return value, however thats not enough for me, I would like to see the full event logs and the debug trace of that simulated transaction.

is that possible using todays tools?

One other possibility is to modify an implementation of the EVM an execute the call there, but not sure where to start to achieve that..

Comment: Not a problem. You can use the `Truffle & Ganache` combination - Truffle in order to run your JS code, and Ganache in order to simulate the node.

Comment: From your question, I am guessing that you are a front-end developer, correct? If so, then you might want to find the best block-chain developer in your company and ask him. I bet that he will know exactly what to do.

Comment: correct..... :)